# gcloud app deploy eror The "vpcaccess.connectors.use" permission is required

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, permissions, permission-denied

I have GO application and tried to deploy it to the google app engine with google command line sdk from a local machine with a custom service account.

I create a custom service account with roles:

- App Engine Admin
- Cloud Build Service Account
- Cloud Build Service
- Agent Serverless VPC Access User

And authorized locally with this account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account account_name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=key.json
```

Also, I configure the service account in my app.yaml:

```
service_account: account_name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

But when i try to deploy

```
gcloud app deploy -v 1
```

I get the error:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Operation is not allowed. The "vpcaccess.connectors.use" permission is required.
```

I can not understand why vpcaccess.connectors.use permission still required even I have **Serverless VPC Access User** role? I found the role on [this google docs page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

Maybe someone has met with a similar difficulty? Please help me)

UPD even i give Owner role i steel have the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i fix this error by removing vpc_access_connector: configuration from app.yaml

UPD
But if you need to configure vpc_access_connector you need to add
Serverless VPC Access User and Compute Viewer IAM roles and all must work fine.

Answer (score 12):

One way to fix this error is by removing `vpc_access_connector:` configuration from app.yaml, however that means your app engine needs to connect via the internet to reach the resources on your subnet.

If you do need vpc_access_connector configured, add
`Serverless VPC Access User` and `Compute Viewer` IAM roles to the service account doing the deployment. Add the roles to the project where the VPC Access connector is configured.

This error will also appear when the connector does not exist (or exists somewhere else).

Check the project-id, region and connector name in app.yaml are correct and refer to a connector that exists in
https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/connectors/list?project=<project_id>

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/project-id/locations/the-zone/connectors/my-connector-name
```

If you have a Shared VPC, the serverless access connector can either be in the host project or the service project. See: [Configure connectors in Shared VPC service projects](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/shared-vpc-service-projects)

If the connector is on a host project of a Shared VPC you must give the  deploying service account `Serverless VPC Access Viewer` (vpcaccess.viewer) role on the host project.
`Compute Network Viewer` (compute.networkViewer) on the host is also recommended.